# SQL Server 2016 INSTEAD OF DELETE Trigger not executing with a MERGE

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am using an INSTEAD OF DELETE Trigger on a table, which works fine with a normal delete statement. But it does not get executed with a Merge statement, like the following one:

```
MERGE INTO table 
USING source on (table.key = source.key) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
   DELETE;
```

I changed it to a cursor, and it works fine. However, I am interested in why does this trigger did not work using a MERGE?

Comment: Do you also perform other operations from the `merge`, and if so, do you have `instead of` triggers [defined for them as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql#trigger-implementation)?

Comment: No, that is everything in the MERGE, and only one trigger.